# How to get selected image's information from system photo using flutter

Tags: flutter

How to get selected image's information from system photo using flutter.
e.g.(longitudes,latitudes,photo time,Height,Width ...)

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. You should at least add some code where your problem is visible to potential helpers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can check out this library.
This will give all the information that you described. 
photo_manager: ^0.4.6

https://pub.dev/packages/photo_manager

Comment: if you think the answer is what you want then mark an answer as accepted, so this can help others.